# Is there a limit on the maximum of number of lines which can be printed to console by BlueJ?

Tags: bluej

I have a simple main method which includes dozens of "System.out.print" as depicted below:

```
public class StudentTester
{
    public static void main()
    {

        System.out.print('\f');

        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println("3");
        System.out.println("4");
        System.out.println("5");
        System.out.println("6");
        System.out.println("7");
        System.out.println("8");
        System.out.println("9");
        System.out.println("10");
        System.out.println("11");
        System.out.println("12");
        System.out.println("13");
        System.out.println("14");
        System.out.println("15");
        System.out.println("16");
        System.out.println("17");
        System.out.println("18");
        System.out.println("19");
        System.out.println("20");
        System.out.println("21");
        System.out.println("22");
        System.out.println("23");
        System.out.println("24");
        System.out.println("25");
        System.out.println("26");
        System.out.println("27");
        System.out.println("28");
        System.out.println("29");
        System.out.println("30");
        System.out.println("31");
        System.out.println("32");
        System.out.println("33");
        System.out.println("34");
        System.out.println("35");
        System.out.println("36");
        System.out.println("37");
        System.out.println("38");
        System.out.println("39");
        System.out.println("40");
        System.out.println("41");
        System.out.println("42");
        System.out.println("43");
        System.out.println("44");
        System.out.println("45");
        System.out.println("46");
        System.out.println("47");
        System.out.println("48");
        System.out.println("49");
        System.out.println("50");
        System.out.println("51");
        System.out.println("52");
        System.out.println("53");
        System.out.println("54");
        System.out.println("55");
        System.out.println("56");
        System.out.println("57");
        System.out.println("58");
        System.out.println("59");        
        System.out.println("60");
        System.out.println("61");
        System.out.println("62");
        System.out.println("63");
        System.out.println("64");
        System.out.println("65");
        System.out.println("66");
        System.out.println("67");
        System.out.println("68");
        System.out.println("69");
        System.out.println("70");

}
```

However, when I run the program, BlueJ shows ONLY 24-70.

Why?

Comment: It sounds like a bug with BlueJ, honestly.  I'd file a bug report with them.

Comment: @Makoto Before filing a bug report look at my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the BlueJ terminal window Go to `Options` and turn on `Unlimited Buffering`. This will solve your problem. You may also turn on `Clear Screen at method calls` to make each program run on a clear screen.

Comment: What does that mean; unlimited buffering?

Comment: @munchschair If you have a program that have lots of output then normally old output is overwritten as one screen is filled. With *unlimited buffering* this overwriting can be avoided. So basically means that you have unlimited space in your terminal window to print.

Comment: I'm using Windows instead of a Mac. How do I turn on unlimited buffering in that case?

Comment: @3B1BSupporter The answer is not OS specific. I haven't used BlueJ in a long time but Unlimited Buffering should be available both in Windows and mac versions.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders How do I do unlimited buffering in windows? I couldn't find anything on that, and the web doesn't seem too helpful. Shall I ask as a separate question on Stack Overflow?