# Counting how often a number in a Hashset has been picked

Tags: java, arrays, random, hashmap, hashset

Here my code until now:

```
 public void lottoGame() {        
      HashSet<Integer> dups = new HashSet<Integer>();  

      for(int howMany = 1; howMany <= 6; howMany++) {
           int lottoNumber = lottoNum.nextInt(49) + 1;

           while(dups.contains(lottoNumber)) {
                lottoNumber = lottoNum.nextInt(49) + 1;
           } 

           dups.add(lottoNumber);
           randomLotto[howMany] = lottoNumber;

           System.out.println(lottoNumber);

    }
    for(int counter : dups) {
        numberCount[counter]++; //to store the counting of random numbers
    } 

    for(int counting = 1; counting < numberCount.length; counting++) {
        System.out.println(counting + " occurs " + numberCount[counting] + " times");
    }
}
```

So basically, what I did was create a hashset and put in 6 random numbers. In my last 2 for-loops I'm trying to count how often I draw which number and print that out. The problem is, it starts with the 3rd field when printing out, for whatever reason. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Should you instead be starting your last 'for' loop at 0?

Comment: If I would start the first for loop with a 0 it would give me 7 numbers instead of 6, which I don't want to have. Tried doing it with the last for-loop and it still starts at field 3. Here a screenshot: http://puu.sh/whYKh/46b2172585.png

Comment: when you say starts at field 3, you mean it prints "3 occurs..." and just skips "1 occurs..."  and "2 occurs..."? I find that highly unlikely.

Comment: It does indeed do that. @OHGODSPIDERS as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: @TheSTARplow As i thought: please check the setting of the output console of the IDE you are using. You probably have a maximum number of lines set there so that only the last x outputted lines are displayed and earlier ones get deleted. To clarify: Your code does not start printing at 3, thats impossible. Your console simply doesn't show the earlier outputs

Comment: Try to increase max terminal lines to unlimited as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16493165/8082980

Comment: Try to increase terminal buffer size to unlimited, as shown here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16493165/8082980)

Comment: Thank you very much! It finally worked, goddamn blueJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using map it is much simpler here look at this example

```
  public static void lotoGame() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Map<Integer, Integer> loto = new HashMap<>();
    while (loto.keySet().size() < 6) {
        int lottoNumber = rand.nextInt(49) + 1;
        loto.compute(lottoNumber, (key, value) -> value == null ? 1 : ++value);
    }

    loto.forEach((key,value)->{
        System.out.println(key + " occurs " + value + " times");
    });
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with hashmaps before, but I will have to look at them sooner or later, thank you very much, I'll probably be using your code!

Comment: Happy to help, if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example you gave. The output I have is correct. Verify your settings or other code you might not show us.

Look at : [Is there a limit on the maximum of number of lines which can be printed to console by BlueJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493057/is-there-a-limit-on-the-maximum-of-number-of-lines-which-can-be-printed-to-conso)

```
class Test
{
    public void lottoGame()
    {
        int[] randomLotto = new int[50];
        int[] numberCount = new int[50];
        Random lottoNum = new Random();
        HashSet<Integer> dups = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int howMany = 1; howMany <= 6; howMany++)
        {
            int lottoNumber = lottoNum.nextInt(49) + 1;

            while (dups.contains(lottoNumber))
            {
                lottoNumber = lottoNum.nextInt(49) + 1;
            }

            dups.add(lottoNumber);
            randomLotto[howMany] = lottoNumber;

            System.out.println(lottoNumber);

        }
        for (int counter : dups)
        {
            numberCount[counter]++; //to store the counting of random numbers
        }
        for (int counting = 1; counting < numberCount.length; counting++)
        {
            System.out.println(counting + " occurs " + numberCount[counting] + " times");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().lottoGame();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
43
27
38
30
14
8
1 occurs 0 times
2 occurs 0 times
3 occurs 0 times
4 occurs 0 times
5 occurs 0 times
6 occurs 0 times
7 occurs 0 times
8 occurs 1 times
9 occurs 0 times
10 occurs 0 times
11 occurs 0 times
12 occurs 0 times
13 occurs 0 times
14 occurs 1 times
15 occurs 0 times
16 occurs 0 times
17 occurs 0 times
18 occurs 0 times
19 occurs 0 times
20 occurs 0 times
21 occurs 0 times
22 occurs 0 times
23 occurs 0 times
24 occurs 0 times
25 occurs 0 times
26 occurs 0 times
27 occurs 1 times
28 occurs 0 times
29 occurs 0 times
30 occurs 1 times
31 occurs 0 times
32 occurs 0 times
33 occurs 0 times
34 occurs 0 times
35 occurs 0 times
36 occurs 0 times
37 occurs 0 times
38 occurs 1 times
39 occurs 0 times
40 occurs 0 times
41 occurs 0 times
42 occurs 0 times
43 occurs 1 times
44 occurs 0 times
45 occurs 0 times
46 occurs 0 times
47 occurs 0 times
48 occurs 0 times
49 occurs 0 times
```

Comment: weird, I copied your code into a new class and tried it out, still starts with  3. Maybe its a problem with BlueJ?

Comment: Most likely you have a problem with the way your console is set.

Comment: Have a look at the post I added in my answer. They say how to remove the BlueJ limit.

Comment: Yeah thats what I just started suspecting, I guess it has some weird standart setting.